# Referential integrity with One to One using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I'm having two tables - 
Foo { foo_id, name }
Foo_properties { fp_id, foo_id, phoneNumber}

Now I want to map this in my object model using hibernate..
I need a foo_id in Foo_properties  because i want to maintain referential integrity and want to add ON DELETE CASCADE constraint. 
so I mapped the relation in the following way -

```
@Entity
public class Foo{
    @Id
    private long foo_id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "foo")
    private FooProperties fooProperties;
}

@Entity
public class FooProperties{

    @Id
    private long fp_id;

    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id",  nullable = false)
    private Foo foo;
}
```

Now since the owning side is FooProperties class, I'm facing following issues - 
If I set the new instance of FooProperties to Foo the existing FooProperties still remains in DB and hibernate doesn't delete that instance, e.g.

```
Foo foo = entityManager.find(Foo.class, fooId);
foo.setFooProperties(new FooProperties("xxx-xxx-xxx"));
entityManager.merge(foo);
```

This results into the new row in FooProperties table along with the existing one. Now I don't understand how I can change my mapping to so I can have above code (or variant of it) working for all scenarios, that means I need Foo as a owning side and foo_id in FooProperties. Is there any way to define the mapping like this?

NOTE: I already asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356313/how-to-map-this-onetoone-in-hibernate-using-jpa) based on this but I think I wasn't clear in previous question so asked this another one.

Comment: kinda hacky but what about CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHANS?

Comment: in Foo? if so then doesn't work.. since owner side is different and also it is deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were already told to use `orphanRemoval = true` or `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`. However, due to casuistics in interpretation of JPA Specification it wouldn't work as expected for one-to-one relationships ([HHH-5559](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5559)).

You can achieve a proper behaviour of `orphanRemoval` with the following trick:

```
@Entity
public class Foo{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FooProperties> fooProperties;

    public FooProperties getFooProperties() {
        if (fooProperties == null || fooProperties.isEmpty()) return null;
        else return fooProperties.get(0);
    }

    public void setFooProperties(FooProperties newFooProperties) {
        if (fooProperties == null) fooProperties = new ArrayList<FooProperties>();
        else fooProperties.clear();
        if (newFooProperties != null)
            fooProperties.add(newFooProperties);            
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
public class FooProperties{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id",  nullable = false)
    private Foo foo;
    ...
}
```

Or even this, if you don't need `FooPropeties.foo`:

```
@Entity
public class Foo{
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id",  nullable = false)        
    private List<FooProperties> fooProperties;

    // getter/setter as above
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bar` is the owner of the association (as indicated by the `mappedBy` on the inverse side) and thus the cascade has to be set there.

Edit:

To invert that, [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Target_Foreign_Keys.2C_Primary_Key_Join_Columns.2C_Cascade_Primary_Keys) might help.

Comment: @Thomas - yes.. agree. but I guess problem won't be solved, right?

Comment: Depends on what the problem is. Your two points should be solved with that, but for meeting your requirements as well please see my edit. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Thomas - Doing so will not resolve the problem. It only implies that delete the related foo record when bar is deleted where as the requirement is different

Comment: @Thomas - yes.. Doing some POCs based on that.. Thanks for sharing.. Will update you on this :)

Comment: @Thomas - Seriously thinking about simulating a OneToOne using a OneToMany JoinTable.. but wondering whether this is good practice or not :)

Comment: I don't think you have to use a Join Table. Did you try the suggestions about the target foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you to choose from, since you don't want to change your mapping :

1. Do it via your service layer logic. I think you have a similar question already.
2. Use the Hibernate annotation @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN) on the Foo side of the relationship. However this is explicitly Hibenate and JPA 2 doesn't include support for the same.

Comment: yes.. I would like to skip the service layer approach, I'll try the @Cascade annotation of hibernate and will update you on this.

Comment: @Premraj M - If you use the annotation, you will still have to set a null reference to Bar.foo, i.e. bar.setFoo(null), as then only will the bar instance be an orphan. Just doing a foo.setBar(toSomeOtherBar) will not do the trick. I believe this might even throw an exception as the relationship is one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of calling merge on the entity, if you directly call **update on session object** then hibernate will first delete the existing row and then it will add the new one. I implemented the same, but, in my case I used xml for mapping the entity. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Why should Hibernate delete the exisiting row? It doesn't do so.

Comment: I am talking about FooProperties (inner table) and not about Foo. The log of hibernate shows that it first deletes inner table data and then adds the new one.