# JPA-Hibernate - "could not get a field value by reflection getter of .."

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I try to use Hibernate 4.1.5.Final within a Spring MVC 3.1 application.

*(Update : now Hibernate 4.1.6.Final and Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, but still no luck!)*

When I try to delete an entity I get an Exception I don't understand.

Here are the two main classes involved :

**User :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usertable")
public class User extends BaseModel
{ 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(optional=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private FacebookAccount facebookAccount;


    // ...

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FacebookAccount getFacebookAccount()
    {
        return facebookAccount;
    }

    public void setFacebookAccount(FacebookAccount facebookAccount)
    {
        this.facebookAccount = facebookAccount;
    }
}
```

**FacebookAccount :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="facebookAccount")
public class FacebookAccount extends BaseModel
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    // ...

}
```

Let's say I have a reference to a User that has a FacebookAccount. In a transaction (in a @Service) I try to do :

```
user.setFacebookAccount(null);
userRepository.save(user);
```

I also tried :

```
user.setFacebookAccount(null);
facebookAccountRepository.delete(facebookAccount);
```

With both, I get this exception :

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.XXXXX.model.user.User.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.XXXXX.model.user.User.id
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:683) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:516) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

Why is that? getId() *does* exist in User and is public!

Any idea?

**UPDATE :**

I made some more tests and the conclusion is that the problem is "orphanRemoval=true". Without it, I'm able to delete the FacebookAccount using :

```
user.setFacebookAccount(null);
facebookAccountRepository.delete(facebookAccount);
```

But this is not exactly what I want. I'd like the *orphanRemoval* to work!

**UPDATE 2 :**

It seems [there is a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5390332/843699) with orphanRemoval and @OneToOne relations in JPA. I guess I have the same issue?

**UPDATE 3 :**

BaseModel class :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    @Column(name = "dateCreated", nullable = false)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "dateModified", nullable = false)
    private Date dateModified;

    public Date getDateCreated()
    {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getDateModified()
    {
        return dateModified;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    @PreRemove
    protected void prePersist() 
    {
        Date now = DateUtil.now().toDate();
        if(dateCreated == null)
        {
            dateCreated = now;
        }
        dateModified = now;
    }

    @PostUpdate
    @PostPersist
    @PostRemove
    protected void postPersist() 
    {
    }

}
```

**Stacktrace :**

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.XXXXX.model.user.User.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.XXXXX.model.user.User.id
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:683) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:516) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) ~[spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.XXXXX.web.controllers.myprofile.abc.SomeController.facebookAccountConfirmationFormPosted(SomeController.java:272) ~[SomeController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565) [jetty-servlet-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1360) [jetty-servlet-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331) [jetty-servlet-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331) [jetty-servlet-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.XXXXX.util.security.beanutils.AuthenticationManager.doFilter(AuthenticationManager.java:127) [AuthenticationManager.class:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331) [jetty-servlet-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331) [jetty-servlet-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
    at com.XXXXX.util.web.filters.SaveGeneratedDynamicResourcesContentFilter.doFilter(SaveGeneratedDynamicResourcesContentFilter.java:60) ~[SaveGeneratedDynamicResourcesContentFilter.class:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331) [jetty-servlet-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:477) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:452) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:894) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.XXXXX.model.user.User.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4425) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4147) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field com.XXXXX.model.user.User.id to com.XXXXX.model.social.FacebookAccount
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.getLong(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:42) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:18) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    ... 108 common frames omitted
```

**UPDATE 4 :**

[A full and minimal application to reproduce the issue.](https://github.com/electrotype/so12009955) The issue seems to happen using my project web structure (controller/service/repository) so there are no *unit tests* in the application. Instead, you have to run :

```
mvn clean jetty:run
```

Then point your browser to :

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

to trigger the exception. The controller#method that will be called is com.example.web.controllers.TestController#test().

Comment: did you manually type the getters or generate them with IDE i.e. Eclipse? don't write them manually

Comment: Most of the time, I use Eclipse. The setters/getters *are valid* in those classes, I double-checked...

Comment: I dont think you have the same problem. Can you add the BaseModel

Comment: You use in field access so hibernate in this setting take the field value by reflection. I suspect that its problem with your instance aop or somethng similiar that prevent hibernate to get the field value. Look on the stacktrace

Comment: user1495181, thanks for trying to help. BaseModel and stacktrace added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change the mapped :

http://www.coderanch.com/t/542400/ORM/databases/delete-option-cascade-Hibernate-one

Comment: Wow, that actually fix my problem!!! I was using mappedBy on the User side and it seems it has to be on the FacebookAccount side! Now everything works fine. Thanks!! I'm going to give you the 59 points as asoon as I can (it says I have to wait 12h).

Comment: @electrotype so what change did you do?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this implementation `https://github.com/bondarenko/so-12009955` of your issue. It's working smoothly on my end.

Comment: Oleksandr, thanks for the help and for this test! It's really appreciated. The problem is that I've been unable to reproduce the issue using unit tests, on my side too. So I created a full (but minimal) web application to reproduce the issue : https://github.com/electrotype/so12009955 .

Answer (score 1):

If it can help someone...

I still had a problem, this time related [to this](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5559) : the child entity is not removed *when replaced by another entity*. It is only removed when set to NULL.

The workaround I'll use for now is to **force the reuse the same entity in the "parent"**.

For example :

```
public class User extends BaseModel
{ 
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    private FacebookAccount facebookAccount;

    public void setFacebookAccount(FacebookAccount facebookAccount)
    {
        if(facebookAccount != null && this.facebookAccount != null && (facebookAccount.getId() == 0 || this.facebookAccount.getId() != facebookAccount.getId()))
        {
            throw new OneToOneFixMustReUseExistingEntityException();
        }

        this.facebookAccount = facebookAccount;
    }

}
```

... where *OneToOneFixMustReUserExistingEntityException* is a custom Exception.

If I really need to associate a *new instance*, than I'll set the current instance to NULL, save the parent, then associate it to the new instance.

I hope this workaround will always work!